# Programmatically toggle class on ng-include element

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a list of elements that are generated via an ng-switch inside an ng-include inside an ng-repeat.

One of those elements needs visibility toggled based on current value of a scope variable.

On page load, I'm able to act on the `$includeContentLoaded` event, but there is also in-app navigation which changed the ng-repeat elements and (I believe) caches the current template/s. This means if I navigate back to that page (via in-app), the `$includeContentLoaded` event doesn't fire.

Unfortunately, because the element I need to act on is within the ng-include, there's no easy way to ensure that it's ready for manipulation.

My last attempt at this vexing issue was to programmatically toggle a class on the ng-include, then add a style rule that would target only that element. I hoped the toggled class would be cached along with the template so it'd persist when navigated back to...but it doesn't. So I'm at a loss.

Any input?

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('Step3Controller', function ($rootScope, $scope, jsonService) {
    $scope.loadStepDefinition(3);

    var militaryService;

    $scope.toggleVaLoanUse = function() {
        militaryService = jsonService.getParams($scope, 'MilitaryService');
        if(militaryService == 0) {
            $scope.hideVaLoanUse();
        } else {
            $scope.showVaLoanUse();
        }
    };

    $scope.hideVaLoanUse = function() {
        $('#lf_PriorVaLoanUse_container').addClass('noexperience');
    };

    $scope.showVaLoanUse = function() {
        $('#lf_PriorVaLoanUse_container').removeClass('noexperience');
    };

    $scope.fieldChanged = function(fieldObject) {
        if (!$scope.fieldValidation(fieldObject)) {
            return;
        }

        if (fieldObject.name == 'MilitaryService') {
            $scope.toggleVaLoanUse();
        }
    };

    $rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        $scope.toggleVaLoanUse();
    });

});
```

My style rule:

```
#lf_PriorVaLoanUse_container.noexperience {
display: none;
}
```

The relevant ng-repeat code:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in steps[stepIndex].fields" ng-element-ready="fieldsLoaded()">
    <div ng-include="properties.PAGE_INPUT_ENTRIES"></div>
</div>
```

The relevant portion of the ng-include:

```
<div id="lf_{{::field.name}}_container" class="lf-field-container">
    <div class="lf-step-field-label">
        <label id="lf_{{::field.name}}_label" class="lf-step-field-label-text" ng-cloak>{{::field.label}}</label>
        <label id="lf_{{::field.name}}_label_calc" class="lf-step-field-label-text"
               ng-cloak>{{::field.labelCalc}}</label>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="field.fields == undefined">
        <div ng-if="field.display == 'box'">
            <div id="lf_{{::field.name}}"
                 class="lf-step-field-boxes"
                 ng-focus="displayAssistant(field);">
                <div ng-repeat="fieldOption in field.options"
                     class="lf-step-field-box-container lf-step-field-box-{{::field.columns}}"
                     ng-show="fieldOption.hidden!=true">
                    <div value="{{::fieldOption.value}}"
                         ng-class="fieldOption.value==field.value ? 'lf-step-field-box-selected' : 'lf-step-field-box'"
                         ng-click="iconSelected($event); onChangeBox(field); fieldChanged(field);"
                         ng-keypress="iconSelectedEnter($event); onChangeBox(field); fieldChanged(field);"
                         id="lf_{{::field.name}}__{{::fieldOption.value}}"
                         ng-focus="displayAssistant(field);"
                         tabIndex="0">
                        <div class="lf-step-field-box-label">{{::fieldOption.label}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

************ **SOLVED** **********

Got this solved with input from responses.

I got it to work with slight modification.

Modified ng-class a bit:

```
<div ng-class="{noexperience: toggleVaLoan()}" class="lf-field-container" id="..">
```

Then threw this in the controller:

```
$scope.toggleVaLoan = function() {
        militaryService = jsonService.getParams($scope, 'MilitaryService');
        if(militaryService == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `ng-class` directive instead of using jQuery to add and remove your desired class.

HTML

```
<div ng-class="anyExperience" class="lf-field-container" id="..">
```

JS

```
$scope.hideVaLoanUse = function() {
    $scope.anyExperience = "noexperience";
};

$scope.showVaLoanUse = function() {
    $scope.anyExperience = "";
};
```

For more information visit the [AngularJS ngClass API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: I got this to work with slight modification.

See edit in OP.